# Как значение bool сделать как два разных чекбокса и сделать поиск?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть поле в БД и модели, которое имеет булево значение.
Написать в `ActiveForm` или `GridView` один чекбокс для этого значения и организовать поиск

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['is_manager' => $this->is_manager,]);
```

не проблема.

Но как правильно вывести в `ActiveForm` и потом организовать поиск **ПО СПИСКУ** элементов в модели, если в визуальной части элемент представляет из себя два чекбокса? Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в итоге человек может выбрать поиск по людям

- Являющиеся управляющими
- Не являющиеся управляющими
- Оба варианта
- Ни одного из вариантов

Comment: вам нужен не чекбокс а ридио

Comment: @madfan41k вы прочитайте вопрос пожалуйста. Мне не нужен радио

Comment: @СергейМишин если вам нужен чекбокс, то что вы будете искать, когда будут одновременно отмечены Да и Нет  чем это отличается от не выбраных флажков? Если нельзя отметить одновременно оба чекбокса, то это радиокнопка (хотя в дизайне может выглядеть как чекбокс).

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Я попробовал добавить в вопрос. Поиск осуществляется по списку элементов. Соответственно можно выбрать все из возможных значений

Comment: @СергейМишин пример с управляющим, кажется, совершенно всех запутал. Если у вас поле модели это список (set в бд), то создайте нужное количество чекбоксов и для каждого потом добавьте что-то вроде`andWhere(new Expression('find_in_set(:value, my_set_column) > 0'))`

Comment: @ЕгорБанин нет, в бд именно булево

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подумал, и сделал так:

---

В основной модели я создал виртуальное поле:

```
public $isManagerArray = [];
```

В модели поиска `SearchModel` добавил правило:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['isManagerArray', 'in', 'range' => [true, false]],
    ];
}
```

В метод `search` добавил условие фильтрации:

```
public function search($params) {
    ....

    if (count($this->isManagerArray) > 1) {
        $query->where(['AND',['OR',[ 'is_manager' => true],['is_manager' => false]]]);
    } else if (count($this->isManagerArray) > 0) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([ 'is_manager' => $this->isManagerArray[0] ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

мой шаблон с поиском `_search.php` будет иметь поле:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::checkboxList($model->formName().'[isManagerArray]', null, [1 => 'Да', 0 => 'Нет']); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

---

Если  есть решение лучше - пожалуйста поделитесь.